# Testing if a directed, bipartite network is non-random

Tags: r, social-network, igraph

I am struggling with finding a suitable approach to determine if a directed, bipartite network is non-random, i.e., if the relations between the nodes and edges of my empirical network are due to chance or represent a real pattern.

Can anyone suggest a succinct step-by-step approach using the R packages statnet or igraph?

Thanks!